# kde - how to change boot animation

Tags: kubuntu, plymouth

I have also tried following these commands:

```
update-alternatives --display default.plymouth
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and these:

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth
sudo ln -s /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth
```

I have also found a wonderful boot animation (Earth-sunrise link http://www.istitutomajorana.it/scarica2/Animazione-Plus8.tar.gz) with a script inside with these commands:

```
sudo cp -R ~/Animazione-Plus8/Earth-sunrise/ /lib/plymouth/themes/
sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/Earth-sunrise/Earth-sunrise.plymouth 100
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

after all the default kubuntu logo didn't change, so I removed all alternatives with this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

but I still have the same logo. I think it's a kde situation.
So how can I change that boot animation with that one I got (Earth-sunrise.plymouth)?

**edit**:
it doesn't work for real during ubuntu boot , only virtual boot animation works:/ I have followed all the steps but nothing has changed in boot animation.

I don't know maybe my problem is with ATI driver I have or with grub settings. What is the right configuration of grub I should have? I have also grub customizer installed in my distro maybe I have to change something.
this is my /etc/default/grub if it helps: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1587147/

Right now I don't have now boot animation, there only a black screen with some text.

**edit2:**
Ok I found my problem, it's about my gpu (msi 6870 Hawk) and the proprietary ati drivers:
I unistalled old 12.8 (even with those the plymouth animation was not working) because I wanted to update my drivers and while I was with open drivers I finally saw the animation on boot, the problem is that I need ati driver and I had to install new 13.1 and infact now plymoth animation doesn't work any more.
So is there a way to solve the problem, now that I found what it is about?
Thanks

Comment: About the problems with the ATI/AMD drivers: Have you tried the the solution from the /usr/share/doc/plymouth/README.Debian ?

Comment: thanks, it worked, I found the solution, I will post here as answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Download the [Earth-sunrise theme](http://www.istitutomajorana.it/scarica2/Animazione-Plus8.tar.gz).
2. Unpack it
3. Copy the Earth-sunrise folder to `/lib/plymouth/themes/Earth-sunrise.`
   Note ! Ubuntu 16.04 and later are using `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/`. More: [Unable to use a custom splash screen in Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775301/unable-to-use-a-custom-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-16-04lts)
4. Change the `distro_logo.png` and the `distro_name.png`

   [image]
5. Add the Earth-sunrise theme to the Plymouth 'alternatives'.

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth \
   default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/Earth-sunrise/Earth-sunrise.plymouth 50
   ```
6. Set the Earth-sunrise theme as the default

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth

   There are 3 choices for the alternative default.plymouth
   (providing /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

     Selection    Path                                                       Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
     0            /lib/plymouth/themes/kubuntu-logo/kubuntu-logo.plymouth     150       auto mode
     1            /lib/plymouth/themes/Earth-sunrise/Earth-sunrise.plymouth   50        manual mode
     2            /lib/plymouth/themes/kubuntu-logo/kubuntu-logo.plymouth     150       manual mode
   * 3            /lib/plymouth/themes/my-plymouth/my-plymouth.plymouth       50        manual mode

   Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
   update-alternatives: using /lib/plymouth/themes/Earth-sunrise/Earth-sunrise.plymouth to provide /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth (default.plymouth) in manual mode.
   ```
7. Update the initramfs

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
8. Test the theme (install [plymouth-x11](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/plymouth-x11) [image: Install plymouth-x11])

   - Konsole #1

     ```
     sudo plymouthd --debug --tty=`tty` --no-daemon
     ```
   - Konsole #2

     ```
     sudo plymouth show-splash
     ```

   There are two (malformed) test konsoles.

   [image]

   Stopping the test with the command:

   ```
   sudo plymouth --quit
   ```
9. Reboot

   [image]

Seems to work at here.

#### References

- [Ubuntu Plymouth wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth)
- [Kubuntu Forums Example](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?61551-Example-Plymouth-theme)

Comment: Very good answer. Needs upvotes! :)

Comment: thanks it's very good, but when I type

sudo plymouthd --debug --tty=`tty` --no-daemon

I receive this http://paste.ubuntu.com/1581635/ and nothing happens

Comment: @Frank Did you run the `sudo plymouth show-splash` command in a second terminal?

Comment: no second terminal has opened after first command :/

Comment: @Frank No of course not, you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: ok i'm sorry it works :) the problem is that it doesn't work for real during ubuntu boot :/
I have followed all steps but nothing has changed in boot animation

Comment: @Frank If it doesn't work for you, then why did you accept the answer? Anyway, I think there might be something broken about your set up done by previous actions you took in an attempt to get it working. Maybe you can try this in a VM and try to figure out what is different in your current installation.

Answer (score 3):

As an FYI, the script should be changed to the following (for 16.04):

```
sudo cp -R Earth-sunrise/ /usr/share/plymouth/themes/
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/Earth-sunrise/Earth-sunrise.plymouth 100
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth  #here, choose the number of the theme you want to use then hit enter
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Based on the forums here:
[Unable to use a custom splash screen in Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775301/unable-to-use-a-custom-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-16-04lts)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with ati drivers and plymouth by appending this line to /etc/default/grub

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

append this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24, mtrr=3, scroll=ywrap"
```

for me the resolution "1280x1024-24" is ok, you could try others.