# Unable to use a custom splash screen in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: gnome, themes, plymouth

I've downloaded a [theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ubuntu+sunrise+plymouth?content=129696) from GNOME-Look and followed the instructions in the readme file. This is not the first time I've tried installing a custom splash screen. It tells me to do something. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRuqn2sliqA&ab_channel=XPSTECH), and at the end, he tells me to run `sudo update-initramfs -u`, as well as here in this current theme's readme file. Problem tho, is that no matter what I do, I always get this error:

```
W: plymouth module "(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so)" missing, skipping that theme.
```

Admittedly, I'm not new to Ubuntu, but I'm absolutely no expert. I have no idea what to do now.

**EDIT:**
I know that plymouth is already the newest version (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1). when I run `sudo apt-get install plymouth`
Also, I'm running Ubuntu on VirtualBox, so it isn't using proprietary drivers. Resolution and everything is fine. I don't even know if the 
*W: plymouth module "(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so)" missing, skipping that theme* is the cause of the problem, but I'm guessing so. I follow all the steps, it's that at `initramfs -u` which I get this error and then it returns to the old splash screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What alternatives are available to replace the purple boot splash screen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/173329/what-alternatives-are-available-to-replace-the-purple-boot-splash-screen) Follow the instructions here, leave a comment on this question if it does not work.

Comment: @MarkKirby thanks for telling me that. I kept googling "W: plymouth module "(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so)" missing, skipping that theme." and didn't get any relevant results so I just thought of posting here. I didn't think it could have been posted a totally different way. I'll check it, cheers!

Comment: @MarkKirby well I tried what you linked to, with no success. Running `sudo update-initramfs -u` returns `W: plymouth module "(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so)" missing, skipping that theme.` again. I checked through the entire list of issues that people had which was linked to in the solution post, but none of those answered my question. No go. `sudo reboot`, still get old splash screen.

Answer (score 21):

I also encountered this problem, here's how I fixed it.

### The basis of the problem

Put simply, the file layout in Ubuntu 16 changes the location of plymouth themes from `/lib/plymouth/themes` to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` and so all of the theme install scripts that assumed the previous layout now install to the wrong location.  Thus, when **update-initramfs** runs, the source data is not where it's supposed to be which causes this error.

```
plymouth module "(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so)" missing, skipping that theme
```

and because of that, the theme is not installed.  The fallback is the default **ubuntu logo** theme.

### Fixing things

I found it convenient to simply perform things manually, and since you're familiar with Ubuntu, I'll concentrate on describing the approach rather than making it cut-and-paste like.

#### Partially initialize-correct with apt-get

Run the following command which will not only install a number of new themes into the correct location but also will fix the now incorrect *update-alternatives* scheme.

```
apt-get install plymouth-themes
```

after this runs there will be a new directory structure anchored in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` which will have an identical layout to the previous path.

#### Move old themes

Consider if each theme is worth migrating, there might be duplicates in which case use the already installed ones.

```
ls -ltrd /lib/plymouth/themes
ls -ltrd /usr/share/plymouth/themes
```

migrating to the new location is simple; just move the directory as each theme is contained in a directory named after the theme

```
cd /lib/plymouth/themes
mv <theThemeDirectory> /usr/share/plymouth/themes
```

#### Fix old themes

The old themes are self-referential in that the *.plymouth* theme file contains a reference to the directory that the theme is installed.  Change these references to the correct ones (e.g. `vi /usr/share/plymouth/themes/orb/orb.plymouth` and then replace `/lib/plymouth` with `/usr/share/plymouth`).

#### Update list with update-alternatives

Extending the orb example, use update-alternatives to make the theme list selectable.

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/orb/orb.plymouth 100
```

This has the added benefit of leveraging the script **update-plymouth** that is included with most themes from [gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=160).  I'll include the text

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Choose the number of the theme you want to use, then [ENTER]"
echo
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
echo
read -p "Do you want to test the theme? (Y/N) "
if [ "$REPLY" != "n" -a "$REPLY" != "N" ] ; then
 echo
 echo "Running 10-second test..."
 sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0; I<10; I++)); do sleep 1 ; sudo plymouth --update=test$I ; done ; sudo plymouth --quit
fi
exit
```

Running `update-plymouth` will allow you to select the theme you want, automatically build the new initramfs and let you preview it.

### Bonus: use art from deviantart

Armed with this knowledge, we don't blindly have to run an installer, but rather with the understanding that all it takes to install a new theme is

1. copy a theme directory to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`
2. run `update-alternatives` as described above
3. run `update-plymouth`

That gives us access to larger selection of themes of which I think [this sonic theme](http://studiopep.deviantart.com/art/The-Blue-Blur-Plymouth-Theme-for-Linux-2013-442215661) is the best.

Comment: damn, this is insane! Thanks a ton for the quick reply, and man, do I love these forums. You're awesome. I will try what you suggested and get back to you shortly. I was aware that the Plymouth themes directory was different, but wasn't too sure what to do about it. Cheers!

Comment: So let me give you a heads up where this is. I understand the change in Plymouth theme location. I left the folder in the old `/lib/plymouth/ubuntu-sunrise` the way it is. Now, fresh from the unpacked file, I moved it to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`. I already had the Plymouth directory under `/usr`, so running `apt-get install plymouth-themes` gave me the message that was up-to-date. I moved that one theme I needed. I went into the `ubuntu-sunrise.plymouth` file, edited both lines. Did the same even back in `/lib/plymouth/ubuntu-sunrise/ubuntu-sunrise.plymouth`. Did the `update-alternatives.`

Comment: And after that, to make sure, I ran `update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` and made sure it was listed. (Either way, the theme didn't come with a `update-plymouth` script so I had to run stuff manually.) Selected the theme. `sudo update-initramfs -u`, no error messages popped up (WOO!). Then I copied the line of code you gave from the `update-plymouth` that tests the splash screen. Sure enough, it worked. Here was what baffled me though. Immediately after, I ran `sudo reboot` and.... it went back to the old splash screen. ARG!

Comment: Hmm, this feels like a different problem.  If the test is working, then the theme is correct and in the right spot and the initrd should have it.  These animations take over in the 2nd half of the boot process and need grub to have GRUB_GFXMODE=*some relevant value* GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep.  The initial spalsh screen also seems like a direct grub thing rather than plymouth.

Comment: let me retry the entire thing all over again.

Comment: nope, doesn't work no matter what.

Comment: Also note the error "plymouth module is missing" is a generic error.  So, there might be more than one root cause. So, possible solutions can be 1)Check location paths in plymouth file are correct 2)Directory name and plymouth file should be similar (even in lower/upper case)

Comment: Works for me! Thanks. (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04+) I have added this and some more relevant information here - http://rajeshksv.blogspot.in/2017/02/customize-ubuntu-linux-plymouth-splash.html

Comment: Your sonic theme isn't bad but I prefer the **Space Sunrise** theme even if it is hard to find modern instructions. Thanks for posting 16.04 instructions for everyone. +1.

Answer (score 4):

If you have followed @wateim answer and still getting the error `W: plymouth module "(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so)" missing, skipping that theme.` then most probably the theme is old. New theme convention is slightly different

- Theme directory name should match with Plymouth file name. Ex: If Directory name is aurora-penguinis then plymouth file name should be aurora-penguinis.plymouth
- Change ImageDir and ScriptFile in plymouth file to new base location (/usr/share/plymouth/themes/)

Do these changes. It should work :) If you want to start all over again, check out [my blog post](http://rajeshksv.blogspot.in/2017/02/customize-ubuntu-linux-plymouth-splash.html). Its almost same as @wateim answer but with slight modifications (works for me in Ubuntu 16.04+)

Comment: after moving themes to `/usr/` path renaming the theme folder to match the `.plymouth` name did the trick for me

Comment: The thing bout the dir name matching the Plymouth file name was what was causing the trouble for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I also stumbled around with `W: plymouth module "(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so)" missing, skipping that theme.`

I copied over the current theme, in my case `ubuntu-gnome-logo` customized and installed it.

Make sure the `.grub`, `.plymouth` and `.script` files located in your theme have the same name as the theme folder. After proper file renaming the error message was gone and the custom splash screen appeared as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens because the location of the Plymouth files has changed. In older versions of Ubuntu they were located in `/lib/plymouth` but now they are located in `/usr/share/plymouth`. What you have to do is reinstall like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  plymouth-themes
```

Then choose a theme that is in the path `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` after running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Then to save the theme, so that it starts with this at the beginning of the system run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

To test you can execute this command:

```
sudo plymouthd --debug  ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0;I<10;I++)); do sleep 1 ; sudo plymouth --update=event$I ; done ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

If you want the old themes then you have to move them from your old location and edit the file with `*.plymouth` extension with the new path that is `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/your_you` and then install them like this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/BootSplash/BootSplash.plymouth 100
```

Then select it by running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

To start the system with this:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```