# Lubuntu 16.04.1 - No Splash Screen on Boot but it displays on Shutdown

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, plymouth

Just upgraded a 64-bit Lubuntu install to 16.04.1.  Went well except I lost the splash screen on boot.  Oddly, it displays briefly on shutdown.

I enabled the `plymouth:debug` option in `grub` and compared the logfile with that from the virtual machine where I tested the upgrade on (which does display the splash screen).  Ignoring time differences, the first significant difference I see is this:

On the virtual

```
[ply-terminal.c:446]    get_active_vt:Remembering that initial vt is 1
```

On the real

```
ply-terminal.c:446]     get_active_vt:Remembering that initial vt is 7
```

On the virtual machine, the next couple of lines are

```
[./plugin.c:560]     find_controller_for_encoder:Found already lit monitor
[./plugin.c:643]     get_index_of_active_mode:Looking for connector mode index of active mode 800x600
```

But on the real machine I get

```
[./plugin.c:813]      query_device:Could not get card resources
[ply-renderer.c:244]  ply_renderer_open_plugin:could not query rendering device for plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth/renderers/drm.so
```

Which would seem to be indicative of the problem.

It looks like on the real machine plymouth tries to start using tty 7, fails, then falls back to tty 1, which works, but maybe it's too late.  The virtual machine uses tty 1 all along.

But I don't know where to go from here. Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: I'm seeing similar problems. One thing I did stumble across is the fact that plymouth themes appear to have moved under 16.04 from /lib/plymouth/themes/ to /usr/share/plymouth/themes/.

Comment: More info on this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/775301/unable-to-use-a-custom-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-16-04lts

Comment: Thanks. I did find the new dir structure but will read the rest of this, might help.