# Plymouth module missing and no animation or logo while booting

Tags: boot, boot-repair, plymouth

I wasn't being able to install any plymouth splash screen, and got this warning message:

```
W: plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so) missing, skipping that theme.
```

How do I retrieve this "plymouth module"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use a custom splash screen in Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775301/unable-to-use-a-custom-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-16-04lts)

Comment: Thanks for your response

I was following the instructions given there but stopped at 
Fix old themes

The old themes are self-referential in that the .plymouth theme file contains a reference to the directory that the theme is installed. Change these references to the correct ones (e.g. vi /usr/share/plymouth/themes/orb/orb.plymouth and then replace /lib/plymouth with /usr/share/plymouth).

I do not know how to replace one with another :(