# can't install plymouth themes, plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so) is allegedly missing

Tags: boot, plymouth

Okay, let me preface this by saying: I am [other people](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775301/unable-to-use-a-custom-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-16-04lts) have had this problem. [Two](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322684), in fact!
and, I ***have tried their solutions, but they did not work for me***

I'm unable to install any plymouth theme. Every time I run `sudo update-initramfs -u`, i get this output:

```
W: plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so) missing, skipping that theme.
W: plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so) missing, skipping that theme.
```

I am confident that there is nothing wrong with my plymouth themes. What do I do?

Comment: The "`...//.so` part of the filename is incorrect. Have you edited a configuration file? Have you kept track of exactly what you did? Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: i have not edited any configuration files.

also, what? what is a remote procedure?

Comment: By "Remote Procedure" I mean the linked "solutions".

Comment: oh, i see! well, 1) downtime is an eventuality, this is just petty! and archive websites exist for that reason! (although i should've include the precise steps in my first post) 2) oh, that's my bad! i should've mentioned, no, i copied the lines with ctrl c/ctrl shift v. and, 3) the error messages are included in my first post.